# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'xx' has no setter method in class 'class xx' while using PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty function

Tags: java, javabeans, nosuchmethoderror

I am using PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty to invoke my setter method dynamically, but for some reason I keep on getting error. Need your assistance to figure out the root cause. Here is my code:

```
class FileDt {
    String reportName=null;
    String reportLocation=null;

    public String getReportName() {
        return reportName;
    }
    public void setReportName(String reportName) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }
    public String getReportLocation() {
        return reportLocation;
    }
    public void setReportLocation(String reportLocation) {
        this.reportLocation = reportLocation;
    }
}

class Foo {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        FileDt dt = newFileDt();
        // #1
        PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(dt, "reportName", "abc.html");
        // #2
        PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(dt, "reportLocation", "c://");
    }
}
```

Both of these methods throw exception

1. > Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'reportName'
   >       has no setter method in class 'class FileDt'  at
   >       org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:2096)
2. > Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'reportLocation'
   >   has no setter method in class 'class FileDt'  at
   >   org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:2096)

Comment: Did the answer I've provided solve your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(Object bean, String name, Object value))`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#setSimpleProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) works with public methods only. It looks like your class uses package scope (missing `public` keyword in class definition).

Running following example:

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

class FileDt {
    String reportName;
    String reportLocation;

    public String getReportName() {
        return reportName;
    }

    public void setReportName(String reportName) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }

    public String getReportLocation() {
        return reportLocation;
    }

    public void setReportLocation(String reportLocation) {
        this.reportLocation = reportLocation;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        FileDt dt = new FileDt();
        // #1
        PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(dt, "reportName", "abc.html");
        // #2
        PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(dt, "reportLocation", "c://");
    }
}
```

throws an exception you have described:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'reportName' has no setter method in class 'class FileDt'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:2096)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtils.java:928)
    at FileDt.main(FileDt.java:28)
```

Making your class `public` solves the problem:

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class FileDt {
    String reportName;
    String reportLocation;

    public String getReportName() {
        return reportName;
    }

    public void setReportName(String reportName) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }

    public String getReportLocation() {
        return reportLocation;
    }

    public void setReportLocation(String reportLocation) {
        this.reportLocation = reportLocation;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        FileDt dt = new FileDt();
        // #1
        PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(dt, "reportName", "abc.html");
        // #2
        PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(dt, "reportLocation", "c://");
    }
}
```